# Break up a string into substrings

Tags: java

I am able to capture a file name in either a File or String format. 
For example the file paths.

```
\EAM\testing
\EAM\development
\System\Applications\Management
```

I need to break these into different strings or substring so they would be

```
\EAM\testing
String 1: EAM
String 2: testing

\EAM\development
String 1: EAM
String 2: development

\System\Applications\Management
String 1: System
String 2: Applications
String 3: Management
```

For the first two I know i could possibly use

```
int index = myStr.lastIndexOf('@');
String firstPart = myStr.substring(1, index);
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use `String#split(...)`

Comment: in above comment say to use "String.Split". He has make a typo mistake

Comment: @jimmysnn that's not a mistake. This kind of notation comes from [javadoc @link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#link). It's often used to address Java class members.

Comment: ok... maybe you are right! Usually I see with '.'

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] parts = myStr.split("\\");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `String.split()` method to get all the values in an array:

```
String []names = filePathString.split("\\");
for(String name:names) {
   System.out.println("name: " + name);
}
```